How to Mock an Object Created Inside a Method Using Mockito and TestNG
I'm trying to write a unit test for a method in my MyClass that creates an instance of DependentClass and calls its method dependentMethod. In my test, I want to override the behavior of dependentMethod so that it returns false instead of true.
Here is the code for MyClass and DependentClass:
public class MyClass {
    public boolean myMethod() {
        DependentClass dependentObject = new DependentClass();
        return dependentObject.dependentMethod();
    }
}

class DependentClass {
    public boolean dependentMethod() {
        // Original behavior
        return true;
    }
}

And here is the test code I've tried using Mockito and TestNG:
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private DependentClass dependentClassMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        // Arrange
        Mockito.when(dependentClassMock.dependentMethod()).thenReturn(false);

        // Act
        boolean result = myClass.myMethod();

        // Assert
        Assert.assertFalse(result);
    }
}


However, this doesn't work as expected because dependentMethod still returns true during the test. I suspect it's because the DependentClass instance created in myMethod is not the mock instance.
How can I properly mock DependentClass so that dependentMethod returns false when called within myMethod? Is there a way to achieve this without refactoring MyClass significantly?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Yes it does. Thank you! I'll update with an answer.

Thank you to the person that posted this link:
Junit local object mock
This is what how I changed my test class based off of that article:
import org.mockito.*;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockConstruction;
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.*;

public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private MyClass myClass;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        MyClass myClassTest = new MyClass();
        assertTrue(myClassTest.myMethod());
        System.out.println("Original behaviour: " + myClassTest.myMethod());

        try (MockedConstruction<DependentClass> dependentClassMockedConstruction = mockConstruction(DependentClass.class,
                (mock, context) -> {
                    Mockito.when(mock.dependentMethod()).thenReturn(false);
                })){
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            System.out.println("Inside of try block: " + myClass.myMethod());
        }
    }
}

